# coding rules, NO nested if...else?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Our company uses checkstyle to ensure the java source code having no nested if..else. i am trying to get used to it. but i have this doubt, is this a efficient way to improve code quality?

we have many rules,

1. no nested if else
2. Method should be no longer than 50 lines.
3. anonymous inner class no longer than 15 lines.
4. there must be a white space before {, which means we have to use Ctrl+Shift+F to format code.

Comment: What's an embedded `if...else`? Things like `if(...) { if(...) {...} }`?

Comment: @Chi What do you mean by an embedded if else?

Comment: i'm pretty sure he means nested if blocks.

Comment: Indentation going over to the right hand side of the screen typically indicates a problem. This particular coding style seems a bit, er, eccentric. But if you've got this rule, there are probably far more serious things you might want to clear up first.

Comment: Yes, it is nested if else, we can't use if(...) { if(...) {...} }

Comment: What a waste of time.  I hope they are as intense about using junit-type tests, separate and fully valid DEV, QA, and UAT environments with the attendant procedures to for promotion between them, code management best practices, issue tracking, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are arguments for favoring polymorphism over use of switch or if else blocks. Here is a link to a [google tech talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc) discussing the issue

Answer (score 1):

Switch / select case statements are generally more efficient, but that seems like a lot of effort over a fairly small issue.

Comment: Not to mention that `switch` only works on values that evaluate to compile time constants.